# Alphabetical order in czech language

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way how to sort by alphabetic order in certain language? For example, in Czech there are letters like "č" or "š" etc. and these characters are in end of the list, even in the alphabet they are at other place. I think that jetpack compose sorting it by `ASCII` code, but I don't know...

I have idea that I can create such a list with every letter from alphabet with correct order and then sort list of words by this list, but I don't think that is a best idea..

Comment: I assure you they aren't using ASCII code, as Strings in Java and Kotlin aren't ASCII, they're unicode.  ANd yes, there are ways to sort a list of strings by language.  But you'd need to give us the code you're using now for context, as we have no idea what you're actually doing,.

Comment: Just basic list.sortedBy{ it.name }